# Controller variables don't get passed into view after declaring layout: nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I have a rails application and in my controller I have declared

```
def home
        render 'home', layout: nil
        @press_images = Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/media/*.{jpg,jpeg,png}")
            .map{ |path| path.split('/').last}
        puts @press_images
    end
```

And In my view I have

```
= @press_images.each do |p|
   - puts p
```

Unfortunately the instance variable doesn't get passed in from controller. But when I delete the `render 'home', layout: nil` line, it works.

How can I pass in instance variable without having to pass in application layout?

Comment: try to place `render` at the end of method. You render view before declaring variable

Comment: it works like a charm now, may I know why?

Comment: You render view before declaring variable

Comment: Indeed a very rookie mistake. thanks

Comment: please write up an answer I will tick it~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

place `render` at the end of method.

You render view before declaring variable `@press_images`

Answer (score 1):

Change your method like this.

> render should be called at he the end of the method

```
def home
    @press_images = Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/media/*.{jpg,jpeg,png}")
        .map{ |path| path.split('/').last}
    render layout: nil
end
```